# Prove independence of Y,Z

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, independence, binomial-distribution

Consider $Y \sim Binom(n, p)$ and $N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ Let $Z = N-Y$.
Prove that $Y,Z$ are independent.

### Attempt:

\begin{align*}
P(Z=z|Y=y) &= \frac{P(Y=y, Z=z)}{P(Y=y)}\\
&= \frac{P(N=y+z)}{P(Y=y)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{\lambda^{y+z}e^{-y-z}}{(y+z)!}}{{n \choose y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}}
\end{align*}

Comment: You could let $U\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(p\lambda)$ and $V\sim\operatorname{Poisson}((1-p)\lambda)$ be independent, call their sum $N=U+V$, and check that they play the role of your $Y$ and $Z$. In the sense that all distributional facts about $Y$, $Z$, and $N$ hold for $U$, $V$, and $N$.

Comment: Note: $\mathsf P(Z=z, Y=y) ~\neq~ \mathsf P(N=y+z) ~=~ \sum_{x=0}^{y+z} \mathsf P(Y=x, Z=y+z-x)$

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean: $Y\mid N\sim \mathcal {Binom}(N, p)$ , $N\sim \mathcal {Pois}(\lambda)$ , and $Z=N-Y$ ?

Then $\mathsf P(Y= y, Z=z) ~{= \mathsf P(Y=y, N=y+z) \\ = \mathsf P(Y=y\mid N=z+y)~\mathsf P(N=y+z) \\ = \binom{z+y}{y}p^y(1-p)^{z}\cdot \dfrac{\lambda^{z+y}e^{-\lambda}}{(z+y)!} \\ =\dfrac{(y+z)!\;p^y\;(1-p)^z\,\lambda^y\,\lambda^z\,e^{-\lambda p}\, e^{-\lambda(1-p)}}{y!~ z!~(y+z)!} \\ = \dfrac{(\lambda p)^y }{y!}\cdot\dfrac{(\lambda(1-p))^z }{z!}\cdot e^{-\lambda} }$

Hmm, that *almost* looks like the product of two independent Poisson distributions, but the first two terms would need to be multiplied by $e^{-\lambda p}$ and $e^{-\lambda(1-p)}$ respectively.   There is also that extra $e^{-\lambda}$ term.   Oh, what to do?

Then, of course, you would need to show that $Y$ and $Z$ *do actually* have such Poisson distributions.

$$\mathsf P(Y=y)~{=\sum_{z=0}^\infty \mathsf P(Y=y\mid N=y+z)\mathsf P(N=y+z) \\\ddots}$$

And such.

Comment: Sir, why do you write `\mathsf P`? is this a good way to write probability function?(just curious!!!!)

Comment: The font highlights the $\mathsf P$, distinguishing it from the random variables and making it pop out more; especially if you include $p$ as a parameter.  Some use $\mathbb P$ for the same reason.

Comment: @GrahamKemp No. $Y \sim Binom(n,p)$ and is independent of N.

Comment: @user239438 Are you sure? $Y\perp N, Z=N-Y$ would mean $\mathsf P(Y=y, Z=z) ~=~ \mathsf P(Y=y)\,\mathsf P(N=y+z)$, so therefore $\mathsf P(Z=z\mid Y=y)~=~\mathsf P(N=y+z)$ which clearly displays dependency.